# Mirror a case's Chatter feed to another object (ConnectAPI vs sObject)

Tags: apex, trigger, api, chatter, case-object

I've got a requirement to mirror a Case's Chatter feed into another object (for safe-keeping, as it were). My first idea was to try a trigger on the FeedItem object, catch it and clone it, and just switch the ParentId to the other object's Id.

```
    for(FeedItem originalItem: feedItemsMap.get(selectedCase.Id)){
        FeedItem repostedItem = originalItem.clone(false, true, true, true);
        repostedItem.ParentId = newObjectId;
        repostedItems.add(repostedItem);
    }
    insert repostedItems;
```

But apparently this only works for a small subset of possible actions (i.e. TextPost and Comments), and we have a lot of possible feed items like Activities and Emails sent and received.

(Also, I did look into [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/88025/copy-chatter-feed-from-one-object-to-another-of-other-sobject-type) answer but it only covers the basic use cases)

So, after many many hours I turned to the ConnectApi methods and thought, easy enough that I could make a Batch Apex that reads the entire case's feed and just reposts it 1-to-1

```
List<ConnectApi.FeedElement> allFeedItems = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getFeedElementsFromFeed(null, ConnectApi.FeedType.Record, currentCase.Id).elements;

for(ConnectApi.FeedElement feedItem: allFeedItems){
   //container for the reposted element
   ConnectApi.FeedItemInput input = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();

   //set subjectid to new related object id
   input.subjectId = newObjectId;

   ConnectApi.BatchInput batchInput = new ConnectApi.BatchInput(input);
   batchInputs.add(batchInput);
}

ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElementBatch(Network.getNetworkId(), batchInputs);
```

But the ConnectApi is super confusing and this didn't seem to work, so I tried making a Share Instead:

```
ConnectApi.FeedEntityShareCapabilityInput shareInput = new ConnectApi.FeedEntityShareCapabilityInput();
shareInput.feedEntityId = feedItem.Id;

ConnectApi.FeedElementCapabilitiesInput feedElementCapabilitiesInput = new ConnectApi.FeedElementCapabilitiesInput();
feedElementCapabilitiesInput.feedEntityShare = shareInput;

input.capabilities = feedItem.capabilities;
```

This also didn't work,  I got a "INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY]: Operation only allowed on published feed entity on public groups or user profiles" error.

So at this point I'm stuck, any ideas on how I could make this requirement possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have found solution for this requirement?

Comment: @SamuelRobert
Hi!, sadly I ended going with the original solution, managed to talk the customer into accepting that not all of the actions were supported, since it was only a backup of the feed